# MySQL SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a query which will check how many entries I have in my database for the last 7 days, it works, but it only returns the dates where records exist. I would like it to return a 0 for days where there is no data as I am producing a 7 day report.

Any help gratefully received!

```
SELECT DATE(created_date) AS date, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) 
    FROM records 
    WHERE DATE(created_date) = date AND method = 'tw') AS total_records 
FROM records 
WHERE created_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day) 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd03b/1 good resourse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL num.i DAY) AS date, 
       COUNT(r.id) AS total_records 
FROM 
        ( SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL               -- where 0 means today
          SELECT -1 UNION ALL                   -- and -1 is yesterday
          ...
          SELECT -6
        ) AS num
    LEFT JOIN
        records AS r
            ON  r.created_date >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL num.i DAY)
            AND r.created_date < DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1+num.i DAY)
            AND r.method = 'tw'
GROUP BY num.i ;
```

An index on `(method, created_date)` will help efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT case when created_date is null
            then 0
            else DATE(created_date)
       end AS date,
      (SELECT COUNT(id)
       FROM records
       WHERE DATE(created_date) = date 
       AND method = 'tw') AS total_records 
FROM records
WHERE created_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
OR created_date is null
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this query works but it seems very slow (probably my own poor initial attempt is to blame!) it's taking ~10 seconds on a database with 50k records

Comment: Do you have an index on your created_date? You'll want one for this query.

Comment: The `DATE(created_date)` will probably make the index useless (for that part).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect moving the subquery from the `SELECT` clause to the `FROM` clause will improve performance.  However, you don't need a subquery at all, if you just want to count the tw records:

```
SELECT date(created_date) as date, 
       sum(case when method = 'tw' then 1 else 0 end) as total_records
FROM records 
WHERE created_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
group by date(created_date)
```

This will return every day, assuming there is at least one type of record on each day.  By the way, if you have a problem with `created_date` being NULL, then you can include the conditions suggested by Juergen.

Answer (score 1):

Perfomance will depends of how many records you will have in 7-day interval.

```
select date, 
       sum(cnt) 
from (SELECT 
       count(id) as cnt, 
       date(created_date) as date
       FROM records 
      WHERE created_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day)
            and method ='tw' 
            and created_date < now()
      group by date
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 day)) as date)
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 day)) as date)
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 day)) as date)
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 day)) as date)
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 day)) as date)
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)) as date)
      union all (select 0 as cnt, date(NOW()) as date)
     ) t

group by date
```

Comment: Hi, this approach worked on MyISAM but not for InnoDB - is it due to the select 0? each day now returns 0 on the new sql engine. Thanks

Comment: @Jon select 0 uses to add rows with 0 sum, if table hasn't record for that day. I don't know how mysql engine can affect that query.